# C# Web Service won't output JSON, only XML

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, json

I'm trying to use jQuery and JSON with a C# Web Service that I wrote. No matter what, the following code will only output in XML.

**Webservice Code**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

I also have these attributes assigned to the class

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ScheduleComputerDS.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The ASMX page always returns as content type "text/xml". Anything I'm missing?

**EDITS:** In response to a couple answers:

If I have the datatype as just "json" the content is still XML and jQuery also will not call my callback function. If I add the "&callback=?" to the url, IIS throws a HTTP 500 error.

My class does inherit from "System.Web.Services.WebService".

From doing some research on your guys answers, it looks like I do need to mess with WCF. Unfortunately the JSON that is returned is more designed for MS Ajax and is a lot of useless bloat for my use. I may look into an open source library like Jayrock or something similar.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Im new to Stackoverflow so I dont know how this comment is going to look in reference to the others but...

If I have the datatype as just "json" the content is still XML and jQuery also will not call my callback function. If I add the "&callback=?" to the url, IIS throws a HTTP 500 error.

Comment: @TheDude - you can edit your original question to add this information in. There's an edit link under the tags on the bottom left of the question section

Comment: If you can use the WCF REST Starter Kit,  just released a Preview 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the ScriptService attribute just allows the service to automatically create a JavaScript proxy (by appending /js to the endpoint address - ScheduleComputerDS.asmx/js in your case). It does not allow you to call the operations on the service the way you're trying to do.

You could instead use a RESTful WCF service (which requires .NET 3.5) which you can access by sending a properly shaped URI via an HTTP GET.

Answer (score 6):

I think there's a typo:

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

Should be:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: awesome :) i made this mistake recently but i had "script" in there. was copied and pasted from an example

Comment: I know its an old post, I just wanna make sure that everyone new on this, dont fall on the wrong way, its `jsonp` no typo there, check http://json-p.org/

Comment: @LuisSánchez: `jsonp` is not recommended.  leave it `json`.  directly from that link you provided: *"authors who rely on JSON-P for cross-domain Ajax are in fact opening themselves up to potentially just as much mayhem as was attempted to be avoided by implementing the same-origin policy in the first place"*

Answer (score 3):

Rich Strahl has a really basic post that should help you out with this.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/164419.aspx

Comment: This link was very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with datatype `json`?

Also, have a look at Encosia's [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) article on the matter. There's some good info on common pitfalls too.