# ASP.Net web service always return XML not JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

Currenly i use asp.net web service but when i call web service method by ajax call it always return XML not json

i try

[ASP.Net web service won't return JSON - Always XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469189/asp-net-web-service-wont-return-json-always-xml)

but its also not work for me..

JS :-

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://www.quietincomes.com/LoginWebservice.asmx/Demo",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("1" + data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("2" + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
});
```

LoginWebservice.asmx :-

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Demo()
    {
        return "Harshit";
    }
```

where i am wrong..

jsfiddle Example:-

http://jsfiddle.net/EXvqc/

Comment: for a short while there http://www.quietincomes.com/LoginWebservice.asmx/Demo was returning JSON but you need to be returning JSONP, that means looking for a get paramater called "callback" and wrapping your JSON in there (see my answer)

Comment: Does your site need to expose this to other domains or is this sevice only consumed by (pages from) the same domain?

Comment: actually i have a website.. and i have created subdomain by url rewriting and some settings in iis. Now when my site harshit.abc.com calls a webservice to it's own site using complete url like http://www.abc.com/webservice.asmx/demo , then it returns data in my ajax request. but data is always in xml format. and result come in error callback

Comment: No subdomains is considored different origin sub.b.com and b.com cannot make ajax requests to each other unless using cors headers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing or JSONP. Here is something I found that you might use to get JSONP to work: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP (future visitors: sorry for not posting the full answer but that article contained a bit too much info to post here)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.quietincomes.com/LoginWebservice.asmx/Demo. Origin http://shyam.quietincomes.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: If you can't do cors (see url in pref request setting a response header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.allowed.site.com) Then try your JSONP solution. If you're doing cors then return JSON; if you're opting for JSONP then return valid JSONP (see link in previous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use **Post** method to send a request to your web service. And as you have used `JSONP` as it always looks for the callbacks, and you have to define callback methods for it.

Please [Refer](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

And the other thing you have to add like following

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class LoginWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string Demo()
        {
            return "Harshit";
        }
    }
```

Indicates that a Web service can be invoked from script. This class cannot be inherited.

Your **aspx/HTML** will contain

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://www.quietincomes.com/LoginWebservice.asmx/Demo",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("1" + data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("2" + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
});
```

**See output below**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

JSONP is not JSON, JSONP is used to get over the same origin policy (site A cannot make ajax request to site B). To solve this problem site A will create a script tag:

```
document.createElement("script")
```

Then set it's source to site B, usually specifying a callback like www.B?callback=callMe

A typical response of site B would be:

```
callMe({siteBSays:"hello"});
```

JQuery hides creating the javascript element for you so it looks like a normal ajax request. Make sure site B has the right response type headers I think it's text/javascript

Another way to do cross domain requests is that site B has a response header that allows site A making ajax requests to it (cors) by setting a response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin